# format currency for specific local in obj c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, currency, nsnumberformatter

i am getting product price in multiple currency. here is a sample data

CurrencyName CurrencySymbol Pirce
"USD",       "$"            1234.5
"EUR",       "€"            12340.5
"GBP",       "£"            123.4 
"CHF",       "CHF"          12345.0

so i want to format available currency based on type not based iPad/iPhone local format.
for example
$1234.50
1.234,50€
and also i want to display all at a same time.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you want to show it in different localizations. Like the Euros in French or German (with decimal comma) and the CHF in Swiss (with decimal point and probably and apostrophe for separating the thousands).

I would map the currency to a specific localization and the feed it to the nsnumberformatter.

Comment: thanks hol. that was my first thought but is it a scalable solution. later if i have 5 more type then i have to do it again.am i right?

Comment: yes. there is no other way. There is a setLocale methode on the nsumberformatter and you pass a NSLocale which you create with - (id)initWithLocaleIdentifier:(NSString *)string

Comment: thanks hol. finalizing this until more generic solution come along.